# Generate all pairs of keys from a dictionary C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, key, combinations

I would like to create a list of key pairs stored in a dictionary (order is not important)
The result should be similar to the follwoing code that works on array structure:

```
int[] myArray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
List<Tuple<int, int>> list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < myArray.Length; j++)
        list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(myArray[i], myArray[j]));
```

One thing that comes to my mind is to create array of keys using

```
Dictionary.Keys.ToArray()
```

method, and then run the two nested loops.
Maybe there is some other more efficient solution?

EDIT:
The final task is to create a matrix where I can compare every entry with all other entries
The values of the dictionary are not important in this task.
I want to create a list of all combinations of keys (order is not important).

Is there a better way of doing this:

```
Dictionary<int, object> dict = new Dictionary<int, object>();
dict.Add(1, null);
dict.Add(2, null);
dict.Add(3, null);
dict.Add(4, null);
//...

int[] dictKeys = dict.Keys.ToArray();
List<Tuple<int, int>> list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < dictKeys.Length; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < dictKeys.Length; j++)
            list.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(dictKeys[i], dictKeys[j]));
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have is pretty much the simplest possible way to produce the result.

Although it's possible to loop the dictionary keys directly, you should realise them as an array so that you can easily access them by index.

You don't have to create the entire matrix of combinations before using it, though. You can make an enumerator that creates the matrix as you loop through it:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> Combinations(IEnumerable<int> keys) {
  int[] a = keys.ToArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < a.Length; j++) {
      yield return new Tuple<int, int>(a[i], a[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
foreach (Tuple<int, int> t in Combinations(myDictionary.Keys)) {
  // the pair of keys is t.Item1 and t.Item2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this `Linq` query is what you want:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> content = dict.Keys.SelectMany(x => 
            dict.Keys, (x, y) => new Tuple<int,int>(x, y)).ToList();
```

For a dictionary with keys `1, 2, 3` it will give 9 tuples:

(1,1) (1,2) (1,3)
(2,1) (2,2) (2,3)
(3,1) (3,2) (3,3)

Comment: Also a cartesian product.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method which generates a *Cartesian Product*:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cartesian<TFirst, TSecond, TResult>
                                      (this IEnumerable<TFirst> first, 
                                       IEnumerable<TSecond> second, 
                                       Func<TFirst, TSecond, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        if (first == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("first");
        if (second == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("second");
        if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("resultSelector");

        return from item1 in first
               from item2 in second
               select resultSelector(item1, item2);
    }
}
```

And then consume it on your keys:

```
IEnumerable<int> firstKeySet = dict.Keys;
IEnumerable<int> secondKeySet = dict.Keys;
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>> cartasian = firstKeySet
                                                .Cartesian(secondKeySet, 
                                                          (k, v) => 
                                                           new KeyValuePair<int, int>
                                                          (k, v));
```

You can find this and more inside [*MoreLINQ*](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/).

Comment: To compare all combinations you don't need to compare them both way, e.g. as you compare `dict[1]` to `dict[2]` you don't need to compare `dict[2]` to `dict[1]`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by *compare*? I'm not sure i follow.

Comment: The question is about comparing each item in the dictionary with all other items in the dictionary. When you have compared two items, you don't have to swap them and compare them again. When you have the combination `1,2` you don't need the combination `2,1`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following approach:

```
int[] myArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
var query = from x in Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.Length)
            from y in Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.Length)
            select new Tuple<int, int>(x, y);

foreach (var tupel in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tupel);
}
```

Comment: Also a cartesian product.